# Convert CString to _bstr_t

Tags: c++

I'm from `Java` so I confuse about many type of String in `C++`

I have a function input with:

`functionTest(_bstr_t *params) {...}`

Then I have a variable declared as:

`CString paramsInput`

How can I convert `CString` to `_bstr_t` to pass to the function?

Comment: `_bstr_t` is a string type from COM which is a language-independent protocol.  Normally in COM if a function parameter has the type `_bstr_t *` it means it is an output parameter.  It would be useful to read the documentation (or look at the implementation) of `functionTest` to see what this parameter actually means.

Comment: IDK the syntax for CString (which is a Microsoft-specific string type) , but what you will need to do is to make a `_bstr_t` that you use with `functionTest`, and you can copy to and from your CString. If you really want the CString that is, you could just use `_bstr_t` instead.

Comment: So, basically have no way to do the conversion or make a new `_bstr_t` from reading `CString` value?

Comment: in my `functionTest` , `params` just using for reading, not for change value

Comment: One interesting observation - bstr's are already a pointer.  Your function test is taking a pointer to a pointer.  Typical convention is to pass BSTR by value: `functionTest(BSTR params)`  Perhaps it's an in/out pointer in your case.

Answer (score 1):

CComBSTR has overloaded conversion functions.

```
CString paramsInput;
ATL::CComBSTR bstr = paramsInput;
```

/// Or, you can do it as ATL::CComBSTR bstr(paramsInput); 
    functionTest(&bstr);

Please note that if the functionTest() test declares its param argument as `out`, then you need to watch out for a memory leak.  See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdyd6xz6.aspx) for how to handle it:

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are compiling with UNICODE as the default.

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

CComBSTR bstrParamsInput(paramsInput);
functionTest(&bstrParamsInput);
```